# Unexpected Method Call

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I'm using mongomapper to store pages in a db, and I index them first. In the index method, I loop through each word, and check to see if it is already in the words hashmap. If not, I add an empty array to the hash, then push its location to the array.

```
def index_words
  @words = self.body.split(" ")
  @words.each_with_index do |word,i|
    if self.words[word.stem].nil?
      self.words[word.stem] = []
    end
    puts "Called from #{caller[0]}"
    self.words[word.stem].push(i)
  end
end
```

When I run this, I get an undefined method error, saying that `self.words[word.stem]` is nil. Furthermore, this method is actually being called from the loop, when it's only called once in the constructor:

```
def initialize(*args)
  super
  index_words
end
```

The error message is:

```
p = Page.new({author: 'Michael',url: 'michaelfine.me',title: 'Michael Fine',body: 'Body Text'})
called fromPage.rb:19:in `each'
NoMethodError: undefined method `push' for nil:NilClass
from Page.rb:24:in `block in index_words'
from Page.rb:19:in `each'
from Page.rb:19:in `each_with_index'
from Page.rb:19:in `index_words'
from Page.rb:14:in `initialize'
from (irb):103:in `new'
from (irb):103
from /Users/Michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Comment: How is the `word.stem` method defined?

Comment: Why is the call unexpected exactly?

Comment: Arie: It's from the fast_stemmer gem

Comment: Andrew: I thought caller[0] would return the toplevel methods caller, not the block. If that's wrong, then I guess my question is why self.words[word.stem] is nil